# What is the meaning of @JsonManagedReference

Tags: java, json, spring

Why do I have to annotate a @OneToMany field with @JsonManagedReference, what difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

@JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally. @JsonBackReference is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

```
public class User {
public int id;
public String name;

@JsonBackReference
public List<Item> userItems;
}
public class Item {
public int id;
public String itemName;

@JsonManagedReference
public User owner;
}
```

Comment: If I omit `@JsonManagedReference` I see no difference in result. Is there any reason I would need to use this annotation? I don't get why one would need to use it. Only `@JsonBackReference` seems to provide a difference in a OneToMany relationship.